# Optimizing textures in android opengl ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am creating an android application that needs to at any time display 10-20 pictures from a database of 1000 + images. I am currently displaying the pictures as a simple texture in opengl. The current application is being slowed by the multiple calls to bindTexture(), as the 10-20 pictures being displayed are almost constantly swapped.

I have tried optimizing with a texture atlas and that did not help much as the texture atlas has to be constantly reloaded as well. I do not want to resort to scaling down the images just yet. Are there any methods that could optimize the texturing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following suggestions:

- If you are not doing so already, only update sections of the atlas using glTexSubImage2d.
- Use RGB565 data (or maybe RGBA4444 ?), which is half the size of RGBA8888.

If that is still too slow:

- Limit the amount of data you update in the atlas each frame; E.g. update only 1/4 of an image that is not currently displayed. I.e. take 4 frames to update an image, and in the fourth frame, change over the texture coordinates to this new image to display it.

Hope that helps,

cheers, Aert.